# KendoUI unable to run .kendoTooltip on each calendar day after month change occurs

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a simple KendoUI calendar widget implemented with a custom class on each day, which on click is suppose to show a kendoUI ToolTip

```
                $("#calendar").kendoCalendar({
                    month: {
                        // template for dates in month view
                        content: '<div class="tool_tip">#=data.value#</div>'
                    },
                    footer: false
                });


                $(".tool_tip").kendoTooltip({
                    autoHide: false,
                    showOn: "click",
                    position: "top",
                    content: 'Hello'
                });
```

For some odd reason it will only show the tooltip on click of each day for the current month. If I were to change the month the tooltip will no longer show. Also note that the class "tooltip" is injected to all other days in the month as well.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Are you running the `$(".tool_top").kendoTooltip()` plugin after the month changes? Sounds like the new month is re-generating the content and not applying the kendoTooltip to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way that you set the tooltip. Since this is initialized when the Calendar is created but not *refreshed* when you navigate. Elements created after navigating do not have the tooltip associated to it.

You should do:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#calendar").kendoCalendar({
            month: {
                // template for dates in month view
                content: '<div class="tool_tip">#=data.value#</div>'
            },
            footer: false,
            navigate : function () {
                $(".tool_tip").kendoTooltip({
                    autoHide: false,
                    showOn: "click",
                    position: "top",
                    content: 'Hello'
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Check it running here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/kvbse/